# Refactoring an existing wrapper class to wrap a T with the same constructor argument of the wrapper itself

Tags: c++

I have an existing wrapper class to wrap Type T, which can be default constructed, or can be constructed with Type U. And the wrapper itself is constructed by a reference to struct Context.

```
struct Foo {}; // Foo can be default constructed.

// Bar needs an argument to be constructed.
struct Bar {
 public:
  Bar(int i) {...}
  Bar() = deleted;
};

Context cx;
Wrapper<Plain> wrapper{cx};
Wrapper<Bar> wrapper2{cx, 10};
```

Now I have a class, Obj, which also takes Context as constructor argument.
And for the Wrapper to wrap Obj, now I have to provide the same 2 arguments to the wrapper constructor.

```
Context cx;
Wrapper<Obj> wrapper3{cx, cx}; // ugly, would prefer Wrapper<Obj> wrapper3{cx};
```

I tried to use template class specialization on Obj, however there's also some data structures in Wrapper I'd like to use in Wrapper.
Or if I don't have to do full specialization on Obj, how can I use some templates to refactor the existing Wrapper?

Thanks

```
struct Context {};

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
 public:
   Wrapper(Context& cx) : ptr() {
     foo(cx);
   }

  template < typename U>
   Wrapper(Context& cx, U u) : ptr(u) {
     foo(cx);
   }

 private:
   T ptr;
   void foo(Context& cx) {}
};

class Obj {
 public:
   Obj() = delete;

   Obj(Context& cx) {}
};

template <>
class Wrapper<Obj> {
 public:
  explicit Wrapper(Context& cx) : ptr(cx) {
    // how to call foo(Context&) in Wrapper<T>?
//    foo(cx); 
  }

 private:
  Obj ptr;
};

int main() {
  Context cx;
  Wrapper<Obj> w(cx); // without template class speicialization on Obj, I have to use Wrapper<Obj> w(cx, cx);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a better [mcve] where you define all types you talk about? especially `S`, `Obj`, etc.

Comment: updated with the simpler sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can specialize only the constructor to avoid having to redefine the whole class. Also, you can use variadic templates to avoid creating many constructors for each argument:

```
struct Context {};

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
   template<class... U>
   Wrapper(Context& cx, U... u) ;

 private:
   T ptr;
   void foo(Context& cx) {}
};

template <typename T>
template<class... U>
Wrapper<T>::Wrapper(Context& cx, U... u) : ptr(u...) {
    foo(cx);
}

class Obj {
 public:
   Obj() = delete;

   Obj(Context& cx) {}
};

template <>
template<class... U>
Wrapper<Obj>::Wrapper(Context& cx, U... u) : ptr(cx, u...) {
    foo(cx);
}

struct Foo {};

struct Bar {
 public:
  Bar(int i) {}
  Bar() = delete;
};

int main()
{
  Context cx;
  Wrapper<Obj> w0(cx);
  Wrapper<Foo> w1(cx);
  Wrapper<Bar> w2(cx,1);
  return 0;
}
```